# Batch processing html tags

Tags: html, dom

This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234084/batch-html-file-processing because I am not limited to Mac machines. I wanted to do this with Linux.

Anyway, I want to remove a series of tags like:

```
<div id="p-person" role="function="">
*some text here*
</div>
```

And maybe substitute them for

```
<b>.
```

Even if regex could do this job, I would like to learn a more refined method, parsing the dom, since regex won't work for more complex cases.

Comment: Regex works for the most complex cases

Comment: @Ding: no, it doesn't, or it's just a nightmare. Fust research about it here in stackoverflow.

Comment: If you Choose `PHP` to parse the `dom` then i'll give `10/10` to QueryPath [http://querypath.org/] for any complex cases. It works same like `Jquery` and it helped me a lot

Comment: Do you need to do this server-side only?